# how to draw a line horizontally on a line in 3D?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

I have two points

- $P_1(6~096,4~572,0)$
- $P_2(12~192,4~572,9~144)$

in 3D. Distance between the two points is $10~989.7202$. In image you can see as side and front view of it. I want to draw a line horizontally with some specific distance assume as 3000 on it from P1. horizontal line distance is 2800. So how to figure out the points A and B on the line P1,P2?[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiF4g.jpg)

Comment: It's relatively easy to calculate the point on the line that is $3000$ away from $P_1$. But the points $A$ and $B$ are not uniquely defined. To what plane is the line $AB$ perpendicular? Or to what line, in addition to $\bar{P_1 P_2}$?

Comment: I guess you mean that the line $AB$ should be "horizontal". What do you mean, precisely, with that? That the $z$-coordinate should be constant?

Comment: @MattiP. now you can see the axis updated in my picture. yes AB should be horizontal. Z-coordinate will be different for P2 and the midpoint of AB.

Comment: Well, the coordinates of the middle point (3000 away) is easy to calculate:
$$
P_1 + 3000 \frac{P_2 - P_1}{\left| P_2 - P_2 \right|} \approx (7~760.1, ~4572, ~2~496.15)
$$
Now the line $AB$ is parallel to the $y$-axis, so you only need to add to the $y$-coordinate. Can you finish the calculations now?

Comment: @MattiP. thank you Matti. I have started.